# Animating divs in sequence with GSAP Scrolltrigger

Tags: javascript, css, animation, gsap

After a few days of struggling with this I finally decided to post on here for help...
I'm trying to create a fullscreen section on my webpage that has a background image that upon being scrolled into view gets an opacity layer over it and after that opacity layer appears the image should become 50% of width (animate from left to right) and from the left side there should slide in a white "box" with text... the opacity, and the white half with text should happen after the image reaches top of webpage and then these animations should happen one after another...

My problem is that I don't know how to make these animations apear one after another and the white half with text jumps in relay fast.. it should move depending on user scroll (I tried using the scrub feature of GSAP but I didn't know how to use it corectly to achieve what I want...)

P.S this is my first time using GSAP so feel free to correct and point out all the mistakes I made :)

here is the [link to my CodePen...](https://codepen.io/Weindorfer/pen/gORmLjz)

and here is the [imgur link to the video of how this animation has to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzR8V.jpg)

and here is my code:

```js
    gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);
    // layered pinning
    gsap.utils.toArray(".panel").forEach((panel, i) => {
        ScrollTrigger.create({
            trigger: panel,
            start: "top top",
            pin: true,
            pinSpacing: false
        });
    });

    ScrollTrigger.create({
        trigger: 'brand',
        pin: true,
        start: 'top top',
        endtrigger: '.white-half',
        end: () => 'bottom top-=' + window.innerHeight,
    })

    gsap.to(".opacity-layer", {
        xPercent: 0,
        opacity: 0.3,
        scrollTrigger: {
            trigger: ".opacity-layer",
            scrub: true,
            markers: true,
            start: "top 0",
            end: "top top",
        },
        transformOrigin: "left center",
    });

    gsap.from(".white-half", {
        scrollTrigger: {
            trigger: ".white-half",
            scrub: true,
            start: "top top",
            end: "top top",
        },
        x: "-100%",
        transformOrigin: "left center",
    });
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  background: black;
}

.panel {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

#video {
  background-color: black;
}
#video h1 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

#brand {
  background-color: #2ecc71;
}
#brand h1 {
  float: right;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
#brand .opacity-layer {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all 0.28s ease-in;
}
#brand .white-half {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  background: white;
  padding-left: 120px;
  padding-right: 120px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  color: black;
}
#technology {
  background-color: #6c757d;
}
#technology h1 {
  float: right;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
#technology .opacity-layer {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all 0.28s ease-in;
}
#technology .white-half {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  background: white;
  padding-left: 120px;
  padding-right: 120px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  color: black;
}
#map {
  background-color: gray;
}
#map h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.7.1/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.co/gsap@3/dist/gsap.min.js"></script>
<section id="video" class="panel">
    <h1>This is the first section with video...</h1>
</section>

<section id="brand" class="panel">
    <h1>This is the second section with image in background...</h1>
    <div class="opacity-layer"></div>
    <div class="white-half">
        <div class="text-wrapper">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur assumenda eius eos magnam molestias nam, nemo nobis quaerat quis saepe sequi ullam, veritatis, vero voluptatum?
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section id="technology" class="panel">
    <h1>This is the third section with image in background...</h1>
    <div class="opacity-layer"></div>
    <div class="white-half">
        <div class="text-wrapper">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur assumenda eius eos magnam molestias nam, nemo nobis quaerat quis saepe sequi ullam, veritatis, vero voluptatum?
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section id="map" class="panel">
    <h1>This is the section with google maps...</h1>
</section>
```